# Translating to a calculated / absolute position

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

I have a Grid that covers the whole screen, and i translate it to the top of the screen (or back down) with a Storyboard. Now i want to do the same but with a distance of 48px from the top. To do this i calculate the top position in `SlideToPosition` with `SlideToPosition = -GridContent.ActualHeight + 48;`. This is ok when the screen size is static.

> The problem is that there are a lot of situations, where i have to recalculate this position:
>
> - app resizing
> - orientation changes
> - mobile onscreen menu visible
>
> The result is also jittery when resizing and sometimes just wrong. I also tried to use `ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds.Top`, but this is just the same with a different variable. Is there a better way to translate to this position, without having a to recalculate a variable all the time?

[image]

```
<Grid Name="GridContent">
    <Grid Name="GridTranslate">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="TranslateTransformContent" />
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
    </Grid>
</Grid>

<Storyboard x:Name="StoryboardUp">
     <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TranslateTransformContent" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y" To="{x:Bind Path=SlideToPosition, Mode=OneWay}" Duration="0:0:0.4">
</Storyboard>

<Storyboard x:Name="StoryboardDown">
     <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TranslateTransformContent" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.4">
</Storyboard>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems a bit off here because you are basically offsetting your grid to a negative location instead of resizing it.

If you insist on that approach than I suggest the following:

Measure your application window height when it is in a "good state" (e.g 1280x720).
Translate the grid height (48px) to percentage (48 / 720 = 0.0666).
Now every time you want to calculate the top position do: SlideToPosition = AppWindowHeight * 0.666.

Comment: I offset the Grid, because i want the same effect as for example the unlock screen where you push the whole screen up. I want the 48px to be fix in every orientation/situation. Your solution gives me a relative height that is only 48px in (e.g 720) orientation.

Comment: I would advise you against using TranslateTransform in that case. It appears to be unreliable when using negative positions hidden from view. Animate the margins instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you really do not want to resize your grid and just clip everything out of the view, you can use margins to move it around.
To move it up and off the screen and show 48 pixels (heightToShow)

```
private void MoveGridUp(double heightToShow)
    {
        double gridHeight = GridContent.ActualHeight;
        Thickness margin = GridContent.Margin;
        margin.Top = heightToShow - gridHeight;
        GridContent.Margin = margin;
    }
```

Then when you want to move it back you can input the normal margin (topMargin)

```
private void MoveGridDown(double topMargin)
    {
        Thickness margin = GridContent.Margin;
        margin.Top = topMargin;
        GridContent.Margin = margin;
    }
```